# PHP APC "emulated" in win64

Tags: php, x86-64, apc

I have installed apache 2.4.4, php 5.4.17 in a windows server 2008 environment. I used the binaries found at http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=25084

These binaries include APC as apcu.dll. When loaded, in phpinfo under [APC] it says:

`APC support: Emulated`

Does anybody know what this means in practice? Is there going to be any difference compared to standard APC? (for which, btw, doesn't seem to exist working binaries for this setup)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I had to RTM. For anyone interested, apcu is the APC-user cache replacement for APC, since apc has been superseded by Zend Opcache in php 5.5 (and has an unclear future)

Comment: Thank you. How to configure Zend Opcache? I mean apc.shm_size=64M. Seems it using 64Mb by default?

Comment: @happy_marmoset I don't think you get to define Zend Opcache's memory settings. You only get to define apcu's memory size, which I think is the setting you mention (apc.shm_size)